# Not operator in regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a file and I wish to grep out all the lines that do not start with a timestamp. I tried using the following regex but it did not work:

```
cat myFile | grep '^(?!\[0-9\]$).*$'
```

Any other suggestions or something that I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: *did not work*... Smoke came out of your computer?

Comment: It belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/, but can't find it between the off topic options. Voted for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not simply use grep -v option like this to negate:

```
grep -v "<pattern>" file
```

Let's say you want to grep all the lines in a shell script that are **not commented** ( do not have # at start ) then you can use:

```
grep -v "^\s*#" file.sh
```

Comment: The only *right* answer here: Don't try to negate the pattern, negate the match result. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat myFile | grep '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d'
```

This assumes your timestamp is of the pattern `dddd-dd-dd dd:dd:dd`, but you change it to what matches your timestamp if it's something else.

Note: Unless you're using some kind of cmd chaining, `grep pattern file` is a simpler syntax

BTW: Your use of a double-negative makes me unsure if you *want* the timestamp lines or you want the non-timestamp lines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `not` operator, just use grep as it is most easily used: finding a pattern:

```
grep '^[0-9]' myFile
```